# Константный метод и обращение к элементу класса типа map

Tags: c++, классы, map, const

Предположим, я хочу просто вывести содержимое словаря map используя константный метод класса, в котором этот словарь находится. Очевидно. что компилятор будет ругаться на то, что я хочу изменить элемент словаря, даже если этот элемент будет в словаре. Как оптимально обратиться к элементу, не создавая копию этого словаря и используя константный метод? Ведь если словарь большой, а надо вывести конкретные элементы, то копирование будет отнимать много времени.

Comment: Почему при выводе содержимого компилятор должен ругаться на то, что вы хотите что-то изменить? 8-/ Вы бы не могли привести кусок кода, где это происходит? `map<int,string> m;
    for(auto& i: m)
        cout << i.first << " " << i.second << endl;` - вот вариант вывода - где тут неприятности?

Comment: *"Очевидно. что компилятор будет ругаться"* Ну так добавьте в вопрос код и текст ошибки. Мне вот не очевидно, как можно сделать итерацию по элементам map, чтобы словить такую ошибку.

Comment: `class Test{

public:

    void Prnt()const{

        cout << out[1];

    }
    Test(){
        out[1] = "out";
    }

private:
    map <int, string> out;
};`
Очевидно, потому что при обращении к несуществующему элементу в словаре map, добавляется элемент этого словаря. Компилятор не знает, есть или нет такой элемент заранее, поэтому вызывает ошибку, что я хочу изменить словарь в константном методе. Поэтому это очевидно. Ваш пример пробежится по существующим элементам 100%, поэтому и ошибку не выдаст.

Comment: На будущее, когда пишешь ответ на комментарий, желательно начинать его с @username , иначе человеку не приходит уведомление и он может не ответить. (Вам уведомления приходят всегда, потому что комменты под вашим постом.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо за совет. Не знал этого, учту в будущем

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const std::map<int, int> m = {
    { 1 , 1},
    {2 , 4},
    {3, 9},
    {4, 16}
};

for(std::map<int, int>::const_iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << "Key:" << it->first << " | Value:" << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

Для константного доступа по ключу, можно использовать метод `at`, но тут нужно быть аккуратный, потому что если ключа нет в коллекции - можно схватить исключение.

```
 std::cout << m.at(1); //1
 std::cout << m.at(2); //4
 std::cout << m.at(3); //9
```

Comment: Так я хотел использовать константный метод. Т.е есть класс, в нём есть словарь, есть константный метод, который обращается к конкретному элементу словаря.

Comment: @Bahoo08, нужно определится, какую логику Вы хотите получить, на случай, если ключа нет в ``std::map``. Если точно знаете, чтоб ключ там будет, то используйте ``at`` вместо квадратных скобок ``[]``. Так же можно указать Ваш ``map`` как ``mutable``, и тогда его можно будет менять в константном методе, но мне кажется это не лучший выход. Если ключа может и не быть, то лучше сначала поискать его с помощью ``find``, потом самому решать, что делать в случае его отсутствия - бросать исключение или возвращать значение по умолчанию.

Comment: Спасибо, изучу этот вопрос.

Comment: Все-таки 2018 год на дворе. Если не ranged for, то хоть `auto it = m.begin()` написали бы. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, решил записать именно так для наглядность. Когда то давно, я сам боролся невозможностью пройтись итератором по константному контейнеру, и проблема моя была как раз в том, что использовал ``std::map<int, int>::iterator it``.

Answer (score 3):

Извините, в комментарий не вписывается.

В чем все же проблема? Вот код, который в константном методе выводит содержимое члена `map` - что здесь не так?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct Test
{

    void out() const
    {
        for(auto& i: m)
            cout << i.first << " " << i.second << endl;
    }
    map<int,string> m = {{1,"one"},{2,"two"}};

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test().out();
}
```

Comment: я писал уже выше. Вы просто перебираете известные элементы, это компилятор знает и конфликта нет. Ответ выше уже был дан. Если вы замените range based for на прямое указывание, то компилятор выведет ошибку. Не верите, замените ваше тело метода на `cout << m[1] << endl;`

Comment: Об ЭТОМ вы ничего не писали в вопросе. Перечитайте - где в нем хоть слово об обращении через оператор индекса? Если вам "надо вывести конкретные элементы" - то всегда есть `find()`, который и нужно применять в вашем случае как самый надежный способ. Вы в очередной раз, как многие, спросили не о том, как забить гвоздь, а в какой руке держать микроскоп для забивания гвоздя. Вернее, даже не так -  пытаясь выяснить, в какой руке держать микроскоп для забивания гвоздя, вы спрашиваете, как завернуть шуруп :( Без точного ТЗ результат всегда один - ХЗ :) Формулируйте вопросы верно...

Comment: Ну написал,, что нужно обратиться к элементу, а не к элементам. В вашем примере выводятся элементы. Так что и вы немного не корректно прочли, не смотря на мою не до конца точную формулировку.

Comment: Ну, если для вас обращение к элементу тождественно применению оператора индекса... Мне даже нечего вам возразить :) - настолько на разных языках мы говорим...